# Restructuring DOM searching method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

As part of a Chrome extension I am searching the entire DOM for elements containing specific words inside each ID/Class.

Currently it looks something like:

```
"allSelectors": document.querySelectorAll("[id*='example'][class*='example']"),
"collapse": function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.allSelectors.length; i++) {
                    // Manipulate MyObject.allSelectors[i] etc
                }
},
```

First, I would like to restructure it somehow (possibly using an `array`?) so that it is easy to add new selectors as doing it like this:

```
 document.querySelectorAll("[id*='example'][class*='example'][id*='other'][class*='other']")
```

Isn't easily scaleable or good.

Secondly, I think `document.querySelectorAll` is very slow - the reason I am using it is because I need to search anywhere in an id/class (hence the use of `*=`) and cannot use a big external library (such as jQuery), as this is a small file and is being injected user side.

Is there an any solution to either of these problems? because if there are many matches then this slowness might become an issue.

Comment: And why can't you use an external library?

Comment: @Xan Content script is injected, I want things to be as quick and small in size as possible (but preferably not too ugly also)

Comment: Hm. Why is that a problem? (I suspect there may be a misunderstanding)

Comment: @Xan Because if my content script is only like 6kb, jquery compressed is like 83kb, seems like overkill to inject both.. if a user has many extensions size can matter and maybe some other reason so I made everything in pure JS

Comment: _“Secondly, I think `document.querySelectorAll` is very slow”_ – on the contrary, I think `querySelectorAll` is probably as fast as it gets. After all, this uses the selector engine directly implemented by the browser; anything else implemented in JavaScript will most likely be slower. (And even libraries like jQuery use `querySelectorAll` when it is available in the browser for tasks like this.) If it feels slow, then that is due to the fact that what you want it to do simply is very costly – after all, each and every single element has to be looked through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would totally go for `querySelectorAll`, I don't think it's that slow, and also it totally fits in a situation like yours. I agree with you that adding a library is overkill for this, and additionally it might not be as beneficial as someone thinks (let's [test it here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-queryselectorall/4)).

Then, again I agree with you that the current solution is not very scalable and that the array is the way to go. Here's a very basic implementation using an array:

```
// an array of classes and ids to match
var nodes,
    searches = [
  '[id*="test"]',
  '[class*="example"]'
];

// a simple function to return an array of nodes 
// that match the content of the array
function getNodes(arr){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll( arr.join() ));
}

nodes = getNodes(searches);
```

The good thing is that new classes and ids can be easily added or removed from the array, for example, later on you can add:

```
searches.push('[id*="some"]');

nodes = getNodes(searches); // new nodes will be fetched
```

Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zeruco/4/edit) with a full example code.

Comment: Quick question: why do I have to wrap a `function()` around the `Array.prototype` part to get it to work? If I try `"theArray" : Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(MyObject.selectorArray.join() ))` it has a `runtime` error